# Pandas: How to change column observations based on that observations attributes

Tags: pandas, numpy, case-when

I have a dataframe with a column whose observations start with either a "P" or "N", followed by a number.

```
    df
    Col1         Col2
    ...          "P14"
                 "N13"
```

I want to change the values of these observations inside Col2.

- If the string starts with P, change the observation to just the number.
- Else if the string starts with N, change the observation to the negative of the number.

Using a for loop, I've managed to do this

```py
i = 0
for value in df["Col2"]:
    if df[0] == "P":
        value = int([pvi[1:3])
    ...
    df["Col2"][i] = value
    i += 1
```

But I was wondering if there was a way I can do this using a more pandas/numpy approach. I've gotten this far:

```py
df["Col2"] = np.select(
    [
        df["Col2"].str.startswith("P"), 
        df["Col2"].str.startswith("N"),
    ],
    [
        # Stuck here.
        ???,
        ???
    ],
    default = "Unknown"
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s=pd.Series([float(key[2:]) for key in df['Col2']])
df['Col2']=np.where(df['Col2'].str.contains('P'),s,-s)
print(df)


Col1         Col2
...          14.0
            -13.0
```

Comment: i'm glad to help!